# Use of Ember run loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am trying to understand the actual usage of Ember run loop in apps.

So here is what I have observed

Ember has 2 way bindings..So if I update any attribute value in my JS code, the corresponding change should reflect on the UI automatically.

But in some cases, we have to do something like

```
Ember.run.next 
Ember.run.scheduleOnce
```

etc

I wanted to understand in which cases do we need to add the Ember.run.* & in which scenarios do the values not re-render automatically on UI ?

Answer (score 2):

**Ember.run**

Most of the times you use the Ember run loop if your code uses some non-ember-objects. For instance, if you would combine jQuery with Ember. An example from the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/applications/run-loop/#toc_how-do-i-tell-ember-to-start-a-run-loop):

```
$('a').click(() => {
    Ember.run(() => {  // begin loop
        // do something with Ember objects here
    }); // end loop, jobs are flushed and executed
});
```

You do this so you can be sure all computed properties, observers and other internal Ember stuff is run before you own code does; so in the example above, you can be sure the click handler is in sync with the rest of your app.

If you don't define the Ember run here manually, Ember will try to approximate a beginning and end for you. But I got to say, having some years experience with Ember now, most of the times it does not work (or not work well). So just define it yourself!

---

**Other methods like debounce, throttle, schedule and scheduleOnce**

All the other methods are actually just helper methods. The difference with other libraries (for instance [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) got also `_.debounce` and `_.throttle` functions) is that those methods are linked with the Ember Run loop too.

If you would use an other library, you would end up wrapping the Ember.run method within the functions. Using for instance `Ember.debounce`, you don't have to worry about those things.

For more info, read [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/applications/run-loop/)!